# In Java, what is the difference between the following declarations?

Tags: java

Considering Java. How are these 2 different and why?

```
public void languageChecks() {
    Integer a = 5;
    Integer b = new Integer(5);

    change(a); // a doesn't get incremented. value is 5
    change(b); // b does. value is now 6
}

public void change(Integer a) {
    a++;
}
```

Comment: That is not the result I get.  Are you sure?

Comment: you entire code is NOP, so it can ignored by the VM just fine.

Comment: Are you really certain b gets changed ? if so, your JVM is broken

Comment: You are shure. I get 5 for both. Do you know why ?

Comment: b can only change if you have a buggy java implementation. Better test it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only difference is that

```
Integer b = new Integer(5);
```

guarantees a new object is created.  The first will use an instance from a cache (see [`Integer.valueOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29)).

Both are immutable and the references to both are passed by value (as is everything in Java).  So `change()` has no effect on either.

Comment: Side note: adding cache for integers was somehow poor decision b/c it prevents optimizations. The compiler is never sure if the value will be a new object or not.

Comment: I don't see how it is worse than the alternative (always using the constructor), which **demands** that a new instance be created each time.

Comment: So, you mean to say that Integer a = 5 automatically creates an Integer object?

Comment: @EFreak - Yes it's called auto-boxing

Answer (score 1):

I'd always been taught `a++` was just shorthand for `a = a + 1` in which case a local variable is created named `a` and immediately thrown away when the method returns. There're no methods on Integer that change the value (it's immutable), and likewise no operations on primitive ints that change their value.

Answer (score -1):

Neither call to change() affects the values passed in, because of auto-boxing/unboxing.

```
public void change(Integer a) {
    // This unboxes 'a' into an int, increments it and throws it away
    a++;
}
```

The above code seems to imply that a++ changes the value of a, since it's an object, not a primitive. However, ++ is not overloaded by Integer, so it unboxes it to be able to apply the ++operator on its int. To me the compiler shouldn't allow this.

Comment: But even if `a` were an `int`, `a` would still only be changed locally.  The boxing is of no consequence here.  Anyway, `a` actually IS incremented locally, even when it's an `Integer` (try printing it after that statement)

Comment: Except that the OP expected it to change, assuming so because it was a reference, not an int.